# Does weather affect car handling?

Tags: enduro

A review of [Enduro for the Atari 2600 at 8-Bit Central](https://www.8-bitcentral.com/reviews/2600enduro.html) mentions that "You'll also encounter some weather conditions that affect your visibility and steering control."

I fired my copy up a few times and didn't notice any change in car handling as the weather changed through sun, snow, fog, and night. There were some changes in visibility during the fog and night sequences (which is awesome for a 2600 game), but no difference in the mechanics of car movement. The snow didn't make me skid as in other driving games of the era such as Sega's Turbo.

Does the mechanics of car handling in Enduro change as the weather changes? In other words, is the linked review incorrect or am I simply not noticing the effects of weather on handling?